# Unable to install qt55 in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, rhel6, amazon-ami, qt

I'm trying to install capybara-webkit on centos 7 as per the instructions at https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit but I'm getting an error

```
sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest             | 2.3 kB     00:00     
3729 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package epel-release-6-8.9.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do


sudo yum install qt5-qtwebkit-devel
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
3729 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package qt5-qtwebkit-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**OS:**

```
cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Comment: That's amazon linux, not RHEL.

Comment: You are not using CentOS 7. You can't install packages for CentOS 7 on Amazon Linux. Create a new instance with the correct OS distribution.

Answer (score 2):

In AmazonLinux Qt5 Webkit is available via EPEL repository, you have to do following to have it installed:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install qt5-qtwebkit-devel
```